# python: how to return a DataFrame or a list from a function?

Tags: python, pandas

This question has a big chance to be duplicated but I haven't found an answer yet. However, I'm trying to apply a function to a pandas DataFrame and I want to have a DataFrame back. Followed example is reproducible:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ["1","2"],
                   'Start': datetime.strptime('20160701', '%Y%m%d'),
                   'End': datetime.strptime('20170701', '%Y%m%d'),
                   'Value': [100, 200],
                   'CreditNote': [-20, -30]})
```

My function:

```
def act_value_calc(x):
    start_delta = (x.Start.replace(day=31,month=12) - x.Start).days
    full_delta = (x.End - x.Start).days
    result1 = round( (x.Value + x.CreditNote) / full_delta * start_delta, 2)
    result2 = round( (x.Value + x.CreditNote) - result1, 2)
    return(pd.DataFrame({'r1': [result1],'r2': [result2]}))
```

Why I can not run the following code ...

```
df.apply(act_value_calc, 1)
```

and what should be done to let it run? I mean to get a DataFrame or a list back with `result1` and `result2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it easier for yourself while returning a pandas.Series instead of a pandas.DataFrame:

```
def act_value_calc(x):
    start_delta = (x.Start.replace(day=31,month=12) - x.Start).days
    full_delta = (x.End - x.Start).days
    result1 = round( (x.Value + x.CreditNote) / full_delta * start_delta, 2)
    result2 = round( (x.Value + x.CreditNote) - result1, 2)
    return(pd.Series({'r1': result1,'r2': result2}))

print(df.apply(act_value_calc, 1))
    r1      r2
0   40.11   39.89
1   85.23   84.77
```

Comment: Ahh yeah that's solid too.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a global variable by declaring it within the function and then create a data frame out of it

```
def act_value_calc(x): 
start_delta = (x.Start.replace(day=31,month=12) - x.Start).days
full_delta = (x.End - x.Start).days
result1 = round( (x.Value + x.CreditNote) / full_delta * start_delta, 2)
result2 = round( (x.Value + x.CreditNote) - result1, 2)
global  df ### declaring global variable
df=pd.DataFrame({'r1': [result1],'r2': [result2]})
```

Answer (score 0):

`apply` will return some value per row, or per column, depending on the `axis` argument you provide (I believe you understand this already given you are providing an `axis` arg of 1).

Returning a DataFrame from apply is problematic. What you probably want to do is create a new column with the *values* returned by the function you are applying.

Something like

```
def act_value_calc1(x):
    start_delta = (x.Start.replace(day=31,month=12) - x.Start).days
    full_delta = (x.End - x.Start).days
    result1 = round( (x.Value + x.CreditNote) / full_delta * start_delta, 2)
    return result1

def act_value_calc2(x):
    start_delta = (x.Start.replace(day=31,month=12) - x.Start).days
    full_delta = (x.End - x.Start).days
    result2 = round( (x.Value + x.CreditNote) - x.result1, 2)
    return result2

df['result1'] = df.apply(act_value_calc1, axis=1)
df['result2'] = df.apply(act_value_calc2, axis=1)
```